# how to append data in after success in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

```
},
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var form_data = $(form).serialize();
            console.log(form_data);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: SITE_URL+url,
                data: form_data,
                success: (function (json) {
          if (json.type == "success") {
                          $.each(json, function(i, item) {
                             $('#div1').append("value"+item.name+) ;
                        })

                         var type = 'Created';
                           if(json.value===1 && typeof json.value != 'undefined'){
                            type = 'Update';
                        }

                        //$("#showDetail form").append();
                        resetform($(form).attr('id'));
                        successMessage('Subscription '+type+' Successfuly');
                        getPosts('show='+$('.custome-show-option select').val()+'&page='+$('#PcurrentPage').text());
                    } else {
                        $("#error_div").html('Module already exist');
                    }
                }),
                error: (function (response) {
                    $("#error_div").html('Error in processing');
                })
            });
```

this code is proper work but not show append data of form data where success::function(json) {} where j console.log(json) show  output only 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is actually your problem but:
in your javascript code you should add:

```
dataType:'json'
```

In laravel in controller you should have something like this:

```
return response()->json(['type' => 'success', 'value' => 1, 'items' => $arrayOfItems]);
```

This part should be something like this:

```
$.each(json.items, function(i, item) {
   $('#div1').append("value" + item.name) ;
});
```